# Sequence of analytic function with range in $\mathbb{H}$ converges locally uniformly

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G$ be a region and let $h_n :G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be analyic maps such that $h_n (G) \subset \{\Im z >0\}$. Assume there is a $z_0 \in G$ such that $h_n (z_0) \rightarrow 0$. Prove that $h_n$ converges uniformly in compact subsets of $G$ to $0$.

Any hint here is appreciated. I am not exactly sure how to use what we know about $z_0$. My guess is that the limit being $0$ and $0$ being on $\partial \mathbb{H}$ are related. Is this possibly a Schwarz reflection problem?

Comment: Do you know (the stronger version of) [Montel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montel%27s_theorem#Functions_omitting_two_values)?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I didn't know about the stronger version. I have just looked it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Compose with the conformal map to the unit disk $z \mapsto \frac{i-z}{i+z}$ to get a sequence of functions from $G$ to the unit disk. Since the functions are bounded ( by $1$) this is a normal family so we have the [Montel theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montel%27s_theorem). Let us show that the new family converges to the constant function $1$. Indeed, from every subsequence we can extract another convergent subsequence. That will converge to a function that takes value $1$ at an inside point $z_0$, hence to a constant function $1$ ( by the maximum modulus principle). Hence our sequence converges uniformly on compacts to the constant function $1$.

Comment: Oh this is very nice! I think you meant the constant function $-1$. But I see your point. Mapping to the disk is a nice little trick that I always seem to forget. Thanks @orangeskid

Comment: @GaussTheBauss: my pleasure. Corrected to get the constant $1$, thanks for pointing that out.